# Change Lat & Lon vectors to matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have some work in R,
Suppose i have following column data

```
Lat Lon Var1 Var2 Var3
```

with the huge number of patterns, since the data are vector i want to change that data  into grid matrix. for example

```
    Lon Lon Lon
Lat Var1 Var1 Var1
Lat Var1 Var1 Var1
Lat Var1 Var1 Var1
```

what is the most effective command in R, thanks

Comment: Please see [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the SO R FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, Lat~Lon, value.var='Var1')
```

If you want to change the horizontal/vertical positions

```
m1 <- acast(df, Lon~Lat, value.var='Var1')
dimnames(m1) <- list(rep('Lon', 3), rep('Lat',3))
```

Using @josiber's example, `m1` would be

```
m1
#    Lat Lat Lat
#Lon   1   4   7
#Lon   2   5   8
#Lon   3   6   9
```

Other option would be to use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Var1~Lon+Lat, df)
#   Lat
#Lon 1 2 3
#  1 1 4 7
#  2 2 5 8
#  3 3 6 9
```

Suppose if you need all the `Var's`

```
acast(melt(df, id.var=c('Lat', 'Lon')), Lon~Lat+variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, it's best to post with an example:

```
dat <- data.frame(Lat=rep(1:3, each=3), Lon=rep(1:3, 3), Var1=1:9, Var2=11:19, Var3=21:29)
dat
#   Lat Lon Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1   1   1    1   11   21
# 2   1   2    2   12   22
# 3   1   3    3   13   23
# 4   2   1    4   14   24
# 5   2   2    5   15   25
# 6   2   3    6   16   26
# 7   3   1    7   17   27
# 8   3   2    8   18   28
# 9   3   3    9   19   29
```

It sounds like you're trying to move from long format to wide format; you can do this with the `reshape` function:

```
reshape(dat[,c("Lon", "Lat", "Var1")], timevar="Lon", idvar="Lat", direction="wide")
#   Lat Var1.1 Var1.2 Var1.3
# 1   1      1      2      3
# 4   2      4      5      6
# 7   3      7      8      9
```

Comment: thanks before for the sample.
in cased if i wanna change into a matrix with lat (vertical) lon (horizontal) and var1 (values)